# SwiftUI - NavigationLink. How to route depending on a backend response?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I still dont understand how to make it work in case you want the view to push another depending on a backend response. So imagine I have 3 possible routes in my landing splashview and depending on the tokenaccess check I have to push to login screen, home screen or change password screen. How can I make a router in this scenario?

Comment: There is `NavigationLink` constructor with tag for this purpose. I can propose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692268/12299030) topic as example of activating different links with different tags by some external condition.

Comment: Your logic takes place at the scenedelegate, how can I move all that lines to a customView ? I am trying to replacate it and I get "... may be missing as an ancestor of this..."